# Server not accessible

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, server-message-block

So this server is driving me a little crazy. I have an HP Server Running Windows 2008. (I know super old)
Anywhere on it's Local network people can access the files on it and connect to it, I can even RPD into it.
Anyone not on the Local network but connected to it via site to site VPN cannot connect to it what so ever. However they can ping it. Firewall is disabled, anti-virus disabled, everything and this is the only server out of a bunch in that network. The rest of the servers vary from Win 2008 to Win 2016.
 It just "started" I know something had to change to cause this but I'm at a loss of what...

I have been looking at DNS as we all know, it couldn't be DNS, and later it turns out to be DNS.. but I haven't found anything yet that would have caused this. I've checked the VPN connections and everything else is working as expected. The site to site is created via Sonicwall.

Sporadically though it will connect and everything will be great, maybe 25% of the time it will connect for maybe 60 seconds. Then drop the connection again. In my tests if one computer can't connect another may be able to connect at the same time and both computers are remote and not in the local network.

I'll run a netstat, and I'll occasionally see one two people across the VPN connecting, but still can't isolate what's causing this.

Any suggestions?

---

**Edit:** Sonicwall Support looked at this issue and confirmed they beleive it's the server as it's giving reset packets. However it's still only ever occuring for users not on the network. 

The server is in the domain and has the internet connection as a domain connection not a public one.

Comment: Smells like MTU to me, to be honest. Possibly something else in the TCP stack, if this is the only affected server - maybe try some tuning like enabling/disabling TCP offload, or one of those other stupid things?

Comment: Running a packet capture, either from Sonicwall if possible, or from the server and from a remote client, might shed some light on the exact problem, or you could throw a few darts at the things I suggested above.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy" but your statement `Anyone not on the Local network but connected to it via site to site VPN cannot connect to it what so ever` really doesn't mean anything. Should we assume you mean connecting to shared folders? Or are they connecting to a website on the server? Or maybe to an FTP site? Or connecting to a CRM or ERP application? What exactly can't they "connect" to?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, server if server is 10.1.1.2 user is 10.1.1.3 it works, but if user at another site, 10.2.1.1 tries to connect that's where the error occurs so I think the issue is in the VPN as it only happens to VPN connections to the server.
The users are connecting to shared folders on the server but the issue also occurs if I initiate an RDP from over the VPN.